# Listen for jQuery UI button change and then update a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am sure that this is a simple situation and probably somewhat common, but I'm stuck and can't quite seem to figure it out.

I am using the jQuery UI Buttons for checkboxes.  I want it so that if a user clicks one, jquery will then make a change to a corresponding div towards the bottom of the page.  Ultimately, I plan on having it use .load to populate the div with the contents of another page, but for now, I am find just changing the background color.

Below is the code I am attempting to get working.  I'm not very good with jQuery and I am likely making some simple mistakes.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Button - Checkboxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $( "#check" ).button();
            $( "#format" ).buttonset();
        });
    });
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('checked');
            $("#first").css("background-color","yellow");
        } else {
            alert('un-checked');
            $("#first").css("background-color","red");
        }
    });
</script>
<style>
#format { margin-top: 2em; }
</style>
```

```
<div id="format">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">3</label>
</div>
<!-- The following divs will end up being populated via an ajax call based on checkbox selections -->
<!-- Ultimately, checking a given checkbox should toggle the corresponding div -->
<div id="first">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div id="second">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div id="third">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS so that the .change() function is inside the document ready portion. Otherwise, it's not *active*.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $( "#check" ).button();
            $( "#format" ).buttonset();
        });

    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('checked');
            $("#first").css("background-color","yellow");
        } else {
            alert('un-checked');
            $("#first").css("background-color","red");
        }
    });
});
```